# python не записывает данные в файл при наличии прав

Tags: python-3.7

Пытаюсь записать данные в файл вот так:

```
f = open('test.txt', 'w')
f.write("test")
f.close()

with open('test.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write("test")
```

Первый способ и второй результатов не дают, скрипт запускаю таким образом `E:\cript.py`

Я правильно понимаю, что должен появится в этом же каталог, где и сам скрипт, новый файл с именем test? Почему он не появляется, права вроде как есть, ошибок в консоли никаких нет...

upd: файл создавал вручную, назначал права для всех на все, но текст в нем не появляется

Comment: А он таки запустился? И файл создастся в каталоге в котором вы находитесь во время запуска (скорее всего ваш домашний каталог)

Comment: все работает как надо

Comment: @AlexeyTen, да, вы правы, файлы создавались не там где скрипт, а в каталоге из которого я его запускал. А можно как-то переписать скрипт, чтобы он создавал файлы в том каталоге, где он расположен?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Чтобы создать файл в той папке, где находится скрипт, нужно 1) получить путь к папке, и 2) добавить его к имени файла:

```
import os

folder = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))) # папк, где лежит скрипт 
filepath = os.path.join(folder, "test.txt") # создаем абсолютный путь к файлу
# далее как обычно
f = open(filepath, 'w')
```